# CSS Menu a:hover when in parent div

Tags: css

I'll try to explain this as best I can - I'm playing with a CSS vertical menu, take a look at it here:

http://codepen.io/jgclifton/pen/JIfhy

My question is, how do I ensure that the links keep their hover color when navigating to the submenu of that item.

I hope that makes sense, I tried using a:active but it seemed to have no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the color on the hover state of the `li`:

```
.menu-side-menu-container li:hover > a
{
  #FFFFFF;
}
```

***Live Demo:*** http://jsfiddle.net/xxf9B/1

Comment: Awesome! knew there would be a nice way to do this. I'll accept this when it lets me :)